# Why does `/dev/shm` on an EC2 instance have I/O throughput comparable to an EBS drive?

Tags: amazon-ec2, shared-memory

I recently learned about the convenient "shared memory" file system at `/dev/shm`. I wanted to see if I could use this to speed up a sometimes-disk-bound program that writes to and reads from a directory, so I ran a little experiment on an EC2 instance (c4.8xlarge running Ubuntu 16.04):

```
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /mnt/fake.txt
real    0m21.381s
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /dev/shm/fake.txt
real    0m20.266s
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /dev/null
real    0m14.334s
```

The EC2 instance seems to have a write throughput to `/dev/shm/`, that is comparable to an EBS drive, which was surprising. `htop` indicates that the machine isn't using swap space in order to write to `/dev/shm`. The noticeably faster write to `/dev/null` in the third case indicates that I'm probably not bound by some other factor (e.g. CPU via the implementation of `yes`) in the first two cases.

I ran the same experiment on my personal computer -- enough memory that `/dev/shm` can hold 7.5 GB of `asdfjkl\n` by default, I can dig up more hardware details if anyone thinks they'll matter -- also running Ubuntu 16.04:

```
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /mnt/fake.txt
real    0m36.520s
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /dev/shm/fake.txt
real    0m12.516s
$ time yes asdfjkl | head -1000000000 > /dev/null
real    0m11.252s
```

This is much closer to what I expected. Read throughput (writing to `/dev/null`) on both machines and from both file systems is roughly proportional to write throughput in the corresponding case.

Two other observations, which I don't know quite how to interpret:

- On the EC2 instance, `htop` indicates memory usage comparable to the size of `/dev/shm/fake.txt` once it's written, while on my desktop, it does not.
- On the EC2 instance, concurrent disk write congestion appears to slow down a write to shared memory by an amount comparable to how much the writes to disk were slowed down, while on my desktop, it does not.

Comment: You really need to ask Amazon. They won't tell you, but probably nobody else can.

Comment: You would improve the question by adding details of the swap usage for both systems to it.

Comment: `/dev/zero` might (?) be a better data source.  Interesting question.

Comment: @JdeBP neither machine is using swap, clarified in the question. Thanks